# Pass a string to component from another component tpl in angular2

Tags: angular, components

Is it possible to pass a plain string from a component template to another component? eg..

Component 1 tpl:

```
<survey-step-complete-msg [messageType]="'completed-survey'"></survey-step-complete-msg>
```

Component 2 .ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'survey-step-complete-msg',
    templateUrl: '../../../../public/template/topic/survey-step-complete-msg.html'
})
export class SurveyStepCompleteMsgComponent {
    @Input() messageType;
    constructor(){
        console.log( this.messageType );
    }
}
```

Component 2 tpl:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="messageType">

    <p *ngSwitchCase="completed-survey">Thanks</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="survey-step-required-fields-missing">Stuff missing</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="survey-required-fields-missing">Stuff missing</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="survey-thanks-now-save">Thanks, don't forget to save.</p>

</div>
```

The current result is in the component ts the @input is always undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's undefined in constructor because it's not there yet. Put this console.log in ngOnInit() method. It should be visible there.

also the markup is:

```
*ngSwitchCase="expression"
```

completed-survey is not an expression. try:

```
 <p *ngSwitchCase="'completed-survey'">Thanks</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your switchcase statements in quotes as well.

```
<p *ngSwitchCase="'completed-survey'">Thanks</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with this exact problem early on.  You need to do: messageType="completed-survey" instead of [messageType]="'completed-survey'"

Comment: ahh right ok! thanks a bundle! So much new sytax.. still trying to cram it all in :D

Comment: actually... turned out it was just the double enclosing of the string in the switch that was missing